# Android - Fused location api

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

Fused Location Api
when the google api client get Connected //

```
public void onconnected()
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

but suppose due to no network ,no wifi and no gps the client keeps on checking for location.

so is there any method by which i could terminate it...if 
onlocationchanged doesnot get called in 1 minute or such interval ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to implement your own way to wait up to 1 minute and terminate waiting for location. You also need to act properly with lifecycle and situation when user will get location update earlier.

Comment: But How to do that.i am basically implementing this in a service...which terminates itself  when it gets location..or else the service also keeps running.

Comment: There're few ways to do it, imho simplest one is to add CountDownTimer that will terminate your service in onFinish() callback method